# Is it possible to only subscribe to an endpoint query?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Is it possible to only subscribe to an endpoint query with defined `provideTags` and later cause that endpoint to auto-refetch with `invalidateTags` from another endpoint mutation?

Comment: What do you mean by "only subscribe"?

Comment: @phry - I may have phrased it incorrectly, apologies. I have `someArray` that's populated by a query endpoint (`endpoint1`) on initial load and a mutation that's manually triggered later. The mutation requires `someArray` to be refreshed but by a different endpoint `endpoint2`. Is it possible to load the data initially with `endpoint1` and on mutation, trigger the refresh of `someArray` using `endpoint2` via `invalidateTags`, instead of calling a lazy query explicitly?

Comment: If you get that data from `endpoint1`, the data of `endpoint1` will only every update by having `endpoint1` refresh. Refreshing `endpoint2` will never refresh `endpoint1` - those cache entries are completely independent of each other.

Comment: So can only refresh the array using a different endpoint with it's lazy query trigger. Thanks for the feedback @phry!

Comment: I'm still a bit confused maybe, because of your use of the word `subscribe` in all this. If you have a `useQuery` and the endpoint of that provides "X" and you have a `useMutation` and the endpoint of that invalidates "X", that will make the first `useQuery` refresh. You just made it sound like both were queries.